# How to use flash messaging with redirects in slim 3 and twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm learning to use the slim framework (v3) and I'm stuck with trying to make a redirect with a flash message. I have a home URL and a /flash URI that should set a flash message and redirect to home.

My bootstrap code is:

```
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Container;
use Slim\Flash;
$container = new Container(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' =>  true]]);
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig([
        INC_ROOT. '/app/views',
        INC_ROOT. '/app/views/templates',
        INC_ROOT. '/app/views/templates/partials',], [
            'debug' => true
        ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container['router'],
        $container['request']->getUri()
    ));

    $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $container['flash']);

    return $view;
};
$container['flash'] = function () {
    return new Flash\Messages();
};
$app = new App($container);
```

My routing file is:

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response, $args){
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
})->setName('home');

$app->get('/flash', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    // Set flash message for next request
    $this->flash->addMessage('global', 'This is a message');

    // Redirect
    return $res->withStatus(301)->withHeader("Location", $this->router->pathFor('home'));
});
```

And I'm trying to use the message in twig as:

```
{{ flash.getMessage('global')[0] }}
```

The redirect is happening, but the flash message is not been passed to the new location. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to use a middleware for the flash messages, then you should be able to access the flash messages in your `View`, do this..

```
//Add a middleware to your app
 $app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
   $this->view->offsetSet("flash", $this->flash);
   return $next($request, $response);
});

$app->get('/flash', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    // Set flash message for next request
    $this->flash->addMessage('global', 'This is a message');
    $this->view->render($res, 'home.twig');
});
```

And then call it from View like this,

```
{{ flash.getMessage('global')[0] }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply, it makes logical sense to me! However, the flash message still isn't showing up. Is there an error in how I am trying to render the message in twig?

Comment: This seems to work after a refresh. Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can understand by reading [Slim-Flash](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash) page.

routing file

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response, $args){
    $messages = $this->flash->getMessages()['global'][0];
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig', ['messages' => $messages]);
})->setName('home');

$app->get('/flash', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    // Set flash message for next request
    $this->flash->addMessage('global', 'This is a message');

    // Redirect
    return $res->withStatus(301)->withHeader("Location", $this->router->pathFor('home'));
});
```

twig file

```
{{ messages }}
```